# Change state of mapbox map upon loading

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'm working on a web app with Mapbox and I want to change the state of a created polygon to be selected without clicking upon loading.

I appreciate any help!

```
draw.add({
'id': 'polygon',
'type': 'Feature',
'properties': {},
'geometry': {
    'type': 'Polygon',
    'coordinates': [coordinates],
}
```

});

**Current state**
[image: Current state]

**Desired state**
[image: Desired state]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to enter direct selection mode:

```js
draw.changeMode('direct_select', { featureId: myFeatureId })
```

See the API docs for more info. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-draw/blob/main/docs/API.md

Comment: thank you for your response, it worked with `raw.changeMode('direct_select', { featureId: /* ... */ })` . Just one thing, it enters the first mode again once selected outside the polygon, basically it does not persist !